# Do I have to overload every operator for a class to behave like one of its member variables?

Tags: c++, string, class, c++11, operator-overloading

Given a user defined type such as the following:

```
struct Word{
    std::string word;
    Widget widget;
};
```

Is there a way to make every overloaded operator of the class behave exactly the same as if it was just a string? Or do I have to implement the class the following way:

```
struct Word{

    bool operator < (Word const& lhs) const;
    bool operator > (Word const& lhs) const;
    bool operator <= (Word const& lhs) const;
    bool operator => (Word const& lhs) const;
    bool operator == (Word const& lhs) const;
    bool operator != (Word const& lhs) const;
    //etc...

    std::string word;
    Widget widget;
};
```

making sure I account for every overloaded operation a string contains, and applying the behaviour to just the string value.

Comment: is it just for compare the `word` in your class?

Comment: Well, you could give it a conversion operator, but that isn't perfect.

Comment: @itwasntpete yes, widget should be ignored when making relational comparisons

Comment: @chris What are the downsides to this?  That I might accidentally pass it into a function that takes strings?  This method will still allow me to make all of the relational comparisons with only one overload though, yes?

Comment: depending on your design, you could inherit from std::string.

Comment: @TrevorHickey, Happens more often than you'd think: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed6b123120892e92

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say your best option is to use [`std::rel_ops`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp) that way you only have to implement `==` and `<` and you get the functionality of all of them. Here's a simple example from cppreference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
    int n;
};

bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs.n == rhs.n;
}

bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
{
    return lhs.n < rhs.n;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1 = {1};
    Foo f2 = {2};
    using namespace std::rel_ops;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "not equal?     : " << (f1 != f2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "greater?       : " << (f1 > f2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "less equal?    : " << (f1 <= f2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "greater equal? : " << (f1 >= f2) << '\n';
}
```

If you need a more complete version of this type of thing use [`<boost/operators.hpp>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)

Comment: All I have to do is include "utility" and implement those two methods?

Comment: Pretty much, I'm gonna update the answer to include boost operators too, which is basically relops on steroids

Comment: @TrevorHickey you also have to do `using namespace std::rel_ops`

Comment: @C.R. C++ is full of magic, if you really wanna see something look up CRTP